# Ignore parent class fields serialization

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have to store in Mongo some documents which must be inherited from class from external library (jar):

```
public class ExternalLibraryClass {
  private EventContainer eventContainer;
}

public class MyDocument extends ExternalLibraryClass {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

Spring Data serializes *eventContainer* field from ExternalLibraryClass as expected. How can I force to ignore this field?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using [custom converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters). Something like this

```
public class MyDocumentConverter implements Converter<MyDocument, DBObject> {

  public DBObject convert(MyDocument source) {
    DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
    dbo.put("firstName", source.getFirstName());
    dbo.put("lastName", source.getLastName());
    return dbo;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Can't guarantee this will work, but better approach would be to create a converter for `ExternalLibraryClass`, and ignore the `eventContainer`

```
public class ExternalLibraryClassConverter implements Converter<ExternalLibraryClass, DBObject> {

    public DBObject convert(ExternalLibraryClass source) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
    return dbo;
  }
}
```

Again, this is just an idea, haven't tried it, wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Predrag, but what with the situation when I have many classes which inherited from ExternalLibraryClass (currently I've got about 10 implementations)?

Comment: Check my edited answer (but don't expect it to work :) )